# Write the even perfect number $8128$ as sum of three palindromes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, palindrome

I would like to know, well from your calculations with a computer and your explanation of your computational method, or well with a theoretical argument how to show that an even perfect number, for example $8128$, is the sum of three palindromes.

The motivation is [1] and next paragraph, currently you can read the required justification of my question from the main theorem of [1] from arXiv (currently I don't know what is the journal editing this article).

From [1] you know what base can use, but if it is possible I would like to know the calculations in base $10$ (but if your base is different feel free to add your answer with such). I add as remark that is well known a  representation in basis $2$ for each even perfect number (but we can't use the base $2$), see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

> **Question.** How do you write the even perfect number $8218$ as a sum of three palindromes for a suitable base? **Many thanks.**

If your calculations were with a computer, please explain, if it is possible, your method also with a different even perfect numbers, for example $33550336$.

**Updated.** The question was updated, now I am asking about $8128$ instead $496$.

### References:

[1] Lewis Baxter, Javier Cilleruelo and Florian Luca, *Every positive integer is a sum of three palindromes* (2016). Available from arXiv as **arXiv:1602.06208v2**.

Comment: If some user want to study or ask in these sites Stack Exchange the same problem for odd perfect nubmers, then he or she can feel free to do it, showing hiself/herself approach. That is then the optional question in such case: One knows some facts about odd perfect numbers, if there exists one odd pefect nubmer, Euler's theorem and Thouchard's theorem (and there are more propositions in the literature). Then on assumption that $N$ is an odd perfect nubmer, is it possible deduce facts about the form or the size of the reresentation of $N$ as a sum of three palindromes?

Comment: I have not read the paper you refer to in detail, but it appears to prove its titular claim quite constructively. Is there any reason you cannot just apply the algorithm it presents? And do you have any reason to think that _perfect numbers_ in particular would be an interesting special case (since the paper says that this holds for all numbers, perfect or not).

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and remarks @HenningMakholm I am not able to read the paper, neither to apply such algorithm, and I am waiting answer where the user who answer the question provide us hiself/herself approach. My believes about why it could be interesting are in the body of the post.

Comment: Of course, some of my questions are speculatives, and my approach doing such questions can be wrong. The merit is for those questions with a good mathematical meaning. Thus many thanks for your critics @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think $8128$ is still too small to require an idea beyond guess-and-check.  For example, we quickly see that $$8128 = 8118 + 9 + 1.$$

Even $33550336$ is a bit too small. Some trial and error led to $$33550336 = 33544533 + 4884 + 919.$$

Comment: Many thanks then. Yes I didn' t think about that if the number is very small then one can find easily solutions. I am waiting more answers, but yours is very very good.